# Unable to identify scope needed to integrate

Tags: uber-api, scopes

We are trying to integrate Salesforce(sandbox) with Uber and registered an app with it. At a step , its asking for scope. Not able to find it anywhere in the article. Can someone help me where will it be available.
Below is the article from Uber :-
Scopes
Scopes grant permission to various API endpoints for your app. When requesting an access token to use on behalf of a user, your application will specify which scopes it needs and these will be shown to the user during the OAuth flow. It’s best to limit the scopes you need to the bare minimum so that users can feel confident with your app and the amount of data it can access.

¶ Privileged scopes
Some scopes, such as the request scope, are privileged scopes. By default, privileged scopes are limited to your development team. To use them in production, request Full Access. The good news is you currently have access to these scopes when authorizing your own account or those of the developer accounts you list in your application dashboard (Limited Access). This allows you to start building an app immediately.